# Draw on UIImage to erase and see through, revealing the UIImage layer underneath

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, draw

I spent the last few days trying to find a way, but I'm stuck.
At a certain point of my application I would like two UIImages overlaid, and when I start "drawing" on the first layer it would erase the image and let us see through, to be able to reveal the content underneath.

I don't know my ways in core graphics, and after spending days on the net I'm wondering if it is possible.

Is there anyone who could help me, or point me to the direction I should follow ?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I have answered similar question before. This will be [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17677225/1407017) to you.

Comment: Thanks both of you, Amar, Nitin, you are giving me back hope.. :-) I'll try those and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one ScratchView class and put your Scratch image in initMethod like:-

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        scratchable = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scratchable.jpg"].CGImage;
        width = CGImageGetWidth(scratchable);
        height = CGImageGetHeight(scratchable);
        self.opaque = NO;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

        CFMutableDataRef pixels = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height );
        alphaPixels = CGBitmapContextCreate( CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( pixels ) , width , height , 8 , width , colorspace , kCGImageAlphaNone );
        provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(pixels);


        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(alphaPixels, frame);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(alphaPixels, 20.0);
        CGContextSetLineCap(alphaPixels, kCGLineCapRound);

        CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(width, height, 8, 8, width, provider, nil, NO);
        scratched = CGImageCreateWithMask(scratchable, mask);

        CGImageRelease(mask);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    }
    return self;
}
```

and also create second view class for display image of background after  Scratch

Bellow this example is much useful to you try with this:-

https://github.com/oyiptong/CGScratch

[image]

Comment: Well, I wen to see your github repo, it seems that it will really help me. Thank you for your help, it's really appreciated. :-)